# Order of Growth in a for loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How can I analyze this code fragment to conclude that it is O(N)?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sum++;
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. What analysis have *you* tried?

Comment: Pick a few reasonably small values for N (start with 4, for example), and write out each iteration of loops, then decide if it is O(N)

Comment: @chrylis I've just tried to follow N in the loops, so the result would be (N+2N+4N...) therefore it would be N(1+2+4...). But I feel that this isn't enough to argue that it's O(N).

Comment: Most compilers would eliminate the inner loop to `sum += i`, optimizing this to O(log(n)).  An aggressive compiler would optimize the outer loop as well, to something like `sum = (1 << (32 - _clz(N))) - 1;`, O(1).

Answer (score 3):

The value of i in the outer loop increases exponentially, you can think of it as increasing a binary digit each time.  The number of digits it takes to represent N is log(N).  So the outer loop will execute log(N) times The inner loop will execute

```
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^log(N)
```

The formula for this [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is (updated from Niklas B's comment)

```
1(1 - 2^log(N))/(1 - 2)
= 2^(log(N) + 1) - 1
~= 2N
```

Over all the algorithm will be O(2N + log(N))

but for big-O notation, the 2N component will overwhelm log(N) so overall the complexity is  O(N)

Comment: It's actually `2^(log(N) + 1) - 1`, which is approximately `2N`.

Comment: @Gopichand: O(2N+log(N)), here log(N) is for outer for-loop and 2N is for inner-for loop.these two are added to get the total complexity (aggregate analysis).

Comment: @Gopichand: let N=10.the inner for loop iterated total 1+2+4+8=15 times which is O(N) as describes in answer.now what about the outer 
for loop? its iterated total 4 times,which is O(log N).so 
total iterations=O(N)+O(log N)=O(N).

Comment: @Gopichand:"for(i=0;i<5;i++){for(j=0;j<5;j++){;}}"who said total iterations =5+5=10;I'm not.total outer loop iterations =5,total inner loop iterations=5+5+5+5+5(5 times for each i)=25.so total iterations=25+5=30=5*(5+1)=n*(n+1).you said it is 25, which is definitely wrong.That's where you are mistake.You again forget to add the time which is required for execution the outer loop.NOW YOU THINK ONCE BEFORE YOU COMMENT NEXT TIME!!(I suggest you to go through the analysis of insertion sort from cormen's book.)

Comment: @Gopichand:I think you are a novice in the field of algorithm.do you know how to calculate time complexity of an algorithm? its not only the matter of your 'COUNT'.You have to know how to calculate the time complexity first.once again I'm suggesting you to study it from Cormen's 'Introduction to Algorithms'.